# Loop in form with foreach and session

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops, foreach

I have a form with a loop inside. 
Here is my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">    
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo "Numero ";
    echo $i;
    echo "<input type='text' name='number2[$i]' id='number2{$i}' />";   
}

   ?>
   <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Confirm!">
   </form>
   <?php
   print_r( $_POST  );
if(!isset($submitbutton)) {
    if (isset($_POST['number2']) != "") {
        echo "<b>{$_POST['number2']}</b>, !\n";
        $nI = $_POST['number2'];
    } 
}
?>
```

The output I get is:

> Array ( [number2] => Array ( [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) [submitbutton] => Confirm! ) Array, !

I would like to know how can I put the number in a session.

For example `Session[1]=3, Session[2]=4`

I try with array and foreach but I always get error.

Comment: `isset($submitbutton)` should be `isset($_POST['submitbutton'])`. No? What error are you getting ?

Comment: have you tried with `$_SESSION[1] = 3` with a `session_start()` at the beginning of your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
<?php
// Start a PHP Session
session_start();
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">    
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
        echo "Numero ";
        echo $i;
        echo "<input type='text' name='number2[$i]' id='number2{$i}' />";   
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Confirm!">
</form>
<?php
// If the form was submitted and number2 is an array
if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']) 
        && isset($_POST['number2']) 
        && is_array($_POST['number2'])) {

    // Loop through each posted value and save it to the session
    foreach ($_POST['number2'] as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION["number2_{$key}"] = $value;
    } 
}
echo "number2_1 = " . $_SESSION["number2_1"] . "<br />";
echo "number2_2 = " . $_SESSION["number2_2"] . "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: if I do it I get the following error
Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 1 in Unknown on line 0 Notice: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 2 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Ah, right, you can't have numeric keys in your $_SESSION.  You'll have to put them in an array or prefix them (note my changes).

Answer (score 2):

What error are you getting? Note that `isset()` merely returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so `isset($_POST['number2'])` will never equal the empty string.

Comment: Well, actually, in loose comparison false is equal to an empty string. So `false != ""` *would* evaluate to false.

Comment: Correct, but it would _always_ evaluate to `FALSE`, so the `if` statement would _always_ evaluate to `TRUE`.

Comment: How would it always evaluate to false? If the variable is set, then it will be `(true != "")` which evaluate to true. If the variable is not set, then it will be `(false != "")` which evaluates to false. The extra `!= ""` is not needed, but does not actually change the result of the condition. It's basically like doing `if (isset() != false)` - unnecessary but doesn't break anything.

Comment: Ah! You're right... I've been working in Ruby a bit lately, in which the empty string is not considered `FALSE`. My bad.